# How to create a Custom Javascript in Shopware 6 which I can use in my Twig files?

Tags: javascript, twig, shopware, shopware6

How to create a Custom Javascript Function which I can use on my Templates and where to put it?
Doing a Huge Function Inline in this Twig file seems wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Shopware webpack build configuration. In order to do that, you have to define an entry-point, so webpack knows where to get started. In Shopware 6, this entry-point is a main.js file inside of the following directory: `<plugin root>/src/Resources/app/storefront/src`

By default the compiled js file is saved at `<plugin root>/src/Resources/app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/<plugin-name>.js`. This file will be recognized automatically by shopware.

Test it by using the following command from inside the development template directory:

```
./psh.phar storefront:build
```

**Important note: This might also generate a public directory inside your plugin. Always ship this directory with your plugin, do not exclude or remove it!**

Comment: I am running the production version of Shopware 6. This does not include the psh.phar. How do I build the storefront then?

Comment: @Marcel For SW6 production just do: ./bin/build-storefront.sh