# Shopware: Injection of JS library on FE

Tags: plugins, shopware, shopware6

I'm new to shopware and currently learning plugin development. I'm creating a plugin that needs to load a JavaScript library to be loaded only in PDP and it needs API credentials from the database.
The docs cover how to load JavaScript via JavaScript plugins but I need to fetch data from the BE, are there any docs covering this topic or how do I start implementing this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make (mostly static) data - like a API configuration - from the database available in the Frontend Javascript code, you can print out that data in the Twig template. The Shopware core [assigns such data to the `window` object](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e95f8b5a70b6ec9d2263812aa1869960a81f01ff/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig#L121-L133). You can do the same in your plugin.

To do this, you also have to "transport" the data first to the the Twig file, like [described in another doc page](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page).

Comment: that was kinda the plan(not sure if that's the best practice), but how to correctly import these js files into my twig/view, can I use js `require` inside a script tag? can I add them to the public directory of my plugin then import them somehow to twig?

Comment: That was not clear from the question, essential you asking 2 questions at once. You might want to clarify this a bit or post a second requestion. Is it a third party script or own scripts? Own scripts you include into the build process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411720/how-to-create-a-custom-javascript-in-shopware-6-which-i-can-use-in-my-twig-files